# запоминаем checkbox при обновлении страницы - jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Доброго времени суток! Направьте неопытного ))
Есть страница с кучей checkbox'ов, имена разные, их много...
Подскажите как сделать, что при обновлении страницы их состояние "запоминалось"?

Я так понял, что мне нужна функция $("input:checkbox:checked"), но как ее использовать не знаю! Ну никак мне jquery не дается ((

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для этого используется [LocalStorage](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/) и/или сессия пользователя. В сессии хранятся данные для текущей страницы, а в LocalStorage - обезличенные данные, т.е пользователь может быть не аутентифицирован на сайте. Вообще по Сети есть множество примеров использования этого функционала:

Запись значения:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCheckbox', true);
```

Чтение:

```
var myCheckbox = localStorage.getItem('myCheckbox');
```

Очистка всех значений:

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: вы что имели в виду под сессией? пхп-сессия, которая хранится на стороне сервера, или `sessionStorage` ? и почему там хранится информация только для текущей страницы. А можно ли в сессию записать что-то без аутентификации? А то по вашему как будто нельзя, но на самом то деле можно.

Comment: Под сессией и имел в виду PHP серверную сессию. На сервере можно хранить информацию для любой страницы, а в sessionStorage - только для текущей, к сожалению.

Comment: У вас есть хороший повод, чтобы перечитать справку про `sessionStorage`, поскольку это хранилище работает на время вашего нахождения на сайте, вне зависимости одна страница открыта или вы переходите на следующую. `localStorage`, напротив, позволяет сохранять данные и оффлайн, когда вы покидаете сайт, но его размер ограничен.

Comment: @teran Тогда в принципе можно использовать localStorage или sessionStorage - в итоге они оба наследуют Storage.